# Error in Finding the nth largest number in the unsorted array (containing duplicates) using median of medians algo O(n)

Tags: java

If an array contains 1,7,7,3,6 and if user asks what 2nd largest element is the output should be 7(not 6) since duplicate values are treated as distinct.
This is my code.
I am using Deterministic search to find the suitable pivot .
Its complexity is O(n).
I am stuck at the error generated by my code .
Please do help me.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class deven  {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
        int len=in.nextInt();
        int n=in.nextInt();
        int array[]=new int[len];
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            array[i]=in.nextInt();
        }


        System.out.println(select(array,len,n));

    }

    static int below[];
    static int above[];
    static int pivot;
    static int i;
    static int j;
    static int x;
    static int y;
    static int index;
    static Random rand=new Random();
    static int select(int array[],int len,int n){

        if(len==1)
            return array[0];
        pivot=pivot(array, len);

        below=new int[len];
        above=new int[len];
        //System.out.println("Block");
        x=0;
        y=0;
        int temp=0;
        for(i=0;i<len;i++){
            if(array[i]>pivot){
                below[x++]=array[i];
            }
            else if(array[i]<pivot){
                above[y++]=array[i];
            }
            else {
                if(temp!=0){
                below[x++]=array[i];
            }
                temp=1;
        }
        }

        i = x;
           j = len - y;
        if(n<i) return select(below,x,n);
        else if(n>=j) return(select(above,y,n-j));
        else  return(pivot);



    }

    static int pivot(int array[],int len){
        if(len==1){
            return array[0];
        }
        int numOfGroups=len/5;
        if(len%5!=0){
            numOfGroups++;
        }

        int setOfMedians[]=new int[numOfGroups];
        for (int i = 0 ; i < numOfGroups ; i++)
        {
            int[] subset;
            if(array.length % 5 > 0)
            {
                if (i == numOfGroups - 1)
                {
                    subset = new int[array.length % 5];
                }
                else
                {
                    subset = new int[5];
                }
            }
            else
            {
                subset = new int[5];
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < subset.length ; j++)
            {
                subset[j] = array[5*i+j];
            }
            setOfMedians[i] = median(subset);
        }

        int goodpivot=select(setOfMedians, numOfGroups,numOfGroups/2 );
        return goodpivot;

    }
    static int median(int[] array)
    {
        if (array.length == 1)
        {
            return array[0];
        }
        int smallerCount = 0;
        for (int i = 0 ; i < array.length ; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0 ; j < array.length ; j++)
            {
                if (array[i] < array[j])
                {
                    smallerCount++;
                }
            }
            if (smallerCount == (array.length - 1)/2)
            {
                return array[i];
            }
            smallerCount = 0;
        }
        return -1; 
    }


}
```

**Input**
6
3
1 2 3 1 2 3
**Output**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError  
    at deven.pivot(deven.java:99)  
    at deven.select(deven.java:34)  
    at deven.pivot(deven.java:102)  
    at deven.select(deven.java:34)  
    at deven.select(deven.java:59)  
    at deven.select(deven.java:59)  
    at deven.select(deven.java:59)
```

Comment: That's not the entire stack trace, right?

Comment: yaa.. i just quoted the small portion :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you maintained an equalsCount in addition to your smallerCount, you should be able to detect whether your candidate value is the median when it is also a duplicate.

(Explanation)

You appear to be deliberately returning -1 as an invalid value when your median method fails unexpectedly.  It would be more proper to throw an exception of some sort, but what you really want is for it to never reach that point.

Your algorithm fails when the median is a duplicate.  In the set { 1, 2, 2, 2, 3 }, for example, 2 is the obvious median, but there's never a point where there are exactly 2 values "smaller than" any of the values being verified.

If you count both smaller and equal values, then you can know your candidate to be a median if either your current test passes, or if the smaller count is less than the midpoint AND the smaller + equal count is greater than the midpoint.

Comment: i didnt get.. Can you re explain.

Comment: @cdev -- I added an explanation as requested.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your median method. It should not return -1. In the last line of the median method, instead of

```
return -1;
```

change it to

```
return array[rand.nextInt(array.length)];
```

Please note that this fix is just an attempt to fix the error you have. It's not a good fix in the sense that median method does not return the median. I think the application should be refactored. The idea of the fix is actually in the pivot method. A good pivot is the median. But if you cannot find the median efficiently, then a pivot can be a random choice among the array.

#### Update:

Let's fix the median method:

```
static int median(int[] array) {
    if (array.length == 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("array cannot be empty.");
    }
    
    int mid = array.length / 2;
    for (int candidate : array) {
        int lower = 0;
        int higher = 0;
        for (int value : array) {
            if (value < candidate) {
                lower++;
            }
            else if (value > candidate) {
                higher++;
            }
        }
        if (lower <= mid && higher <= mid) {
            return candidate;
        }
    }
    throw new IllegalStateException();
}
```

Comment: ya you are right but how to correct it. How can i remove that logical error too which i got using ur advise of                         'return array[rand.nextInt(array.length)];'

Comment: @cdev I included a modified version of the median method.